# Why do I get "pointermove" events with undefined movementX/Y on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, web

When I subscribe to "pointermove" events I get events with undefined `movementX` and `movementY` properties. Tried on both Chrome and Safary. Does it mean it's not supported (I have never seen any notes about that in OS compatibility charts)?

**Note**: Tried with and without `touch-action: none`.

Comment: I thought that was strange too. movementX and movementY are `undefined` only in iOS. I filed a Webkit bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=248119